# Roblox API - Send Private Message (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, roblox

I'm trying to make a little script to send private messages to other users using the Roblox API.

This is the end point [/v1/messages/send](https://privatemessages.roblox.com/docs#!/Messages/post_v1_messages_send)
But I can't seem to figure how to use it at all, can someone point me in the right direction or to an already made "NPM" Package that has this function.

Comment: Can you post the source that you have? You need a token to make requests to the Roblox API.

Comment: Questions that ask for module recommendations are likely to be flagged for removal. Please share what you've tried. If you're having trouble understanding the api, ask about what in particular is giving you trobule.